# How to calculate the time with a circle rotating that has a specific duration

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a DJ Vinyl Mixer, so that you can drag the vinyl to a specific time location and let the vinyl carryon playing.

I have a circle which has width and height of 325, so this has a circumference of 1099. If the vinyl is playing and going round in a circle and the music is playing what formula would i need to get the vinyl to play once i have dragged the vinyl to a specific location. I have managed to get the dragging of the vinyl and used the audio element to get the current time. I just dont know how to calculate, lets say if you dragged the vinyl up then the vinyl would rewind and play at the current time once he drag ends.

This is my TouchMove event:

```
        $(document).on('touchmove click', '#round-play1', function(e){
        detectTap = false; // Excludes the scroll events from touch events
        console.log("ddddd");
        detectTapMove = true;

        if (!isStart) return;
        e.preventDefault();
        ang = angXY(e, this) - angStart;
        this.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ang}rad)`;

        console.log("ang1111 " + ang);

        myAudio=document.getElementById('audio2');
        console.log(myAudio.currentTime);

        var x = e.touches[0].clientX;
        var y = e.touches[0].clientY;

        if (y < mY) {
            console.log('Up');


            if(myAudio.currentTime <= 0){

            // myAudio.currentTime = duration - (mY - y);
            }else{

            }

            var ff = 360 / myAudio.duration;
            var dd = (mY - y);

            myAudio.currentTime -= dd;
            console.log("dcurrentTime " + myAudio.currentTime);
            console.log("dduration " + dd);


        } else if (y > mY) {
            console.log('Down');
            myAudio.currentTime += y - mY;
        } else {
            console.log('Moving left-right or the opposite');
        }


        // set new mY after doing test above
        mY = y;

        //r = getCurrentRotation($(this)[0]);
        r = getCurrentRotation($(this)[0]);
    });
```

i also have this code that keeps the record or vinyl rotating:

```
        setInterval(() => {

        if(!detectTapMove){

            if(detectTap == true && rr != undefined){


                r = rr;
                $("#round-play1")[0].style.transform = `rotate(${r}deg)`;
                rr = NaN;
                detectTap = false;
            }else{
                r = r + 1;

                if(r >= 360){
                    r = 0;
                }

                console.log("dcurrentTime " + myAudio.currentTime);
                $("#round-play1")[0].style.transform = `rotate(${r}deg)`;
            }
        }



    }, 100);
```

So what would i need to calculate the exact time when i drag the vinyl to a specific location and let the music carryon playing that has a duration of lets say 251 seconds?

### UPDATE

Thanks @Manatee Pink,

I have managed to integrate your answer, nearly have this working but im stuck. When i drag the vinyl the vinyl drags correctly but when i stop and then try to drag again the vinyl does not stay at its current postion and goes back to the start as you can see in the video. Can you see where im going wrong in the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("body").height($(document).height());
        $("#services").height($(document).height());
        $(".container").height($(document).height());
        $(".row").height($(document).height());

        $("#audioplay1").click(function() {

            myAudio=document.getElementById('audio2');
            duration = myAudio.duration;
            myAudio.currentTime = 0;
            myAudio.loop=true;
            myAudio.play();
            detectTap = false;
            detectTapMove = false;
        })
    })

    let last_Dot_Product;

    $(document).on('touchstart click', '#round-play1', function(e){
        var x = e.touches[0].clientX;
        var y = e.touches[0].clientY;
        
        A_x = x;
        A_y = y;
    });

    $(document).on('touchmove click', '#round-play1', function(e){
        
        var x = e.touches[0].clientX;
        var y = e.touches[0].clientY;

        B_x = x;
        B_y = y;

        AB_x = B_x - A_x;
        AB_y = B_y - A_y;

        C_x = 162.5;
        C_y = 162.5;

        AC_x = C_x - A_x;
        AC_y = C_y - A_y;

        var length = Math.sqrt(AC_x * AC_x + AC_y * AC_y);
        AC_x = AC_x/length;
        AC_y = AC_y/length;

        var tmp = AC_x;
        AC_x = AC_y;
        AC_y = -tmp;

        var dot_product = AB_x * AC_x + AB_y * AC_y;

        $("#round-play1")[0].style.transform = `rotate(${dot_product}deg)`;
        if(dot_product > 0){
            console.log(dot_product)
            console.log("UP")
        }else{
            console.log(dot_product)
            console.log("DOWN")
        }

        

    });


    $(document).on('touchend click', '#round-play1', function(e){
        

        var x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
        var y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;


    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think this is more of a math question than a programming question.

But I'll try to give you an idea.

After clicking on the vinyl, you have to store the xy coordinates of the point where the user has clicked. Let's call those A.

after that, you take the xy coordinates of the mouse cursor, let's call those B, and compute the vector going from A to B, call it AB.

Now, you also need to look at the center of the vinyl, call it C.

Compute the vector going from A to C, call it AC. Then you have to normalize AC, so that its length is 1 like this:

```
var length = sqrt(AC_x * AC_x + AC_y * AC_y);
AC_x = AC_x/length;
AC_y = AC_y/length;
```

Rotate AC 90 degrees to the right. You simply have to switch the x and y coordinates around and negate the y component, like this:

```
var tmp = AC_x;
AC_x = AC_y;
AC_y = -tmp;
```

Then compute the dot product between AB and AC like this:

```
var dot_product = AB_x * AC_x + AB_y * AC_y;
```

The dot product now tells you in what direction the mouse cursor is dragging the vinyl AND how strongly. If the dot product is positive, the vinyl is turned counter-clockwise. If it is negative, it is turned clock-wise. The larger the absolute value is, the faster it is dragged and if it is 0, the mouse cursor tries to drag towards the center, which means it wouldn't move at all.

Now you simply have to update your playcursor according to the direction and the strength of the dot product.

Also, keep in mind that you have to update A and B every frame, A is the mouse position from the previous frame and B is the mouse position from the current frame. So you have to update like this:

```
A = B;
B = mousePosition();
```

hopefully, this helps, I am not well-versed enough in JS to write everything for you in JS code, so you have to figure that part out on your own, but this is the math that you need.

Comment: This is a pretty good answer and you have my upvote but there's an issue - this won't work as-is if the user drags the vinyl more than 360 degrees.

Comment: I don't see how this would be an issue or what that would even mean in this context.

This is a calculation that happens from frame to frame. 

Or do you mean I should have mentioned the boundary conditions when the play cursor reaches one of the ends? I expected OP to take that into account since that wasn't part of the question

Comment: I guess you're right -- this has to be done every frame, no matter how you do the calculation. I had been thinking that a non-vector calculation with polar coordinates would have accounted for this automatically (and it sort of does), but you'd still need to update end position frame by frame.

Comment: Ah ok, I see where you're coming from. Yeah, in this case I don't think you win anything by using polar coordinates

Comment: @ManateePink, i have updated the question, please could you advise.

Comment: @redoc01, I am afraid I don't know enough JS to see what's the problem. The only thing that seems odd to me is that in the last event handler you read the xy coordinates, but don't do anything with it. But I also don't see why that would cause an issue. I'd advise you to ask a new question with this problem and simply link to this question for further details